# List what was in Stock daily, when all you have is the movement of goods

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Problem. I am trying to get what is in Stock on each day from a table.

The problem is that i only have the date and the movement of goods stored in it.

So its basicly like i have an initial iventory from the 01.01.2001 and from that day on i only have the movements. Like incoming and outgoing goods.
For Example:

```
initial inventory: 1000 pcs
01.01.2001: 500 leave the stock - 150 incoming goods.
01.02.2001: 100 leave the stock - 400 incoming goods.
....
```

in order to get what in stock on a specific date you have to send out the folowing query:

```
      SELECT SUM(amount)
      FROM   stock
      WHERE  date <= <date>
```

The Table looks like this:

```
Date       Type Amount
---------- ---- ------
12.31.2000 in     1000
01.01.2001 in      150
01.01.2001 out     500
01.02.2001 in      400
01.02.2001 out     150
01.03.2001 in      300
01.03.2001 out      50
```

The result I want is:

```
Date       Amount
---------- ------
31.12.2000   1000
01.01.2001    650
01.02.2001    900 
01.03.2001   1150
```

The Problem is getting different rows for each date at once.

getting whats in stock is easy:

```
select sum(amount)-(select sum(amount) From stock where type = 'out' and     date <='01.03.2001')
From Stock
where  Type = 'in'
and date <= 01.03.2001
```

Comment: Where are you saving how many left and how many incoming. Where is initial inventory saved? Give stock table sample

Comment: Sorry that the view of the table is terrible.
It is all stored in one table like that.

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43784075/5234334) and let me know if you have any doubt

Comment: thanks alot, i wont get to check it today. but i will let you know tomorrow

Comment: Thanks alot Utsav. Your answer did the trick.

Comment: Welcome. But I'd suggest to check out MT0 answer as that would be faster on large dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 select t.dt,
  sum(curr_stock) over ( order by dt) as stock1
from 
( select dt,
          sum(case when type='out' then -1 * amount
                    else amount end
                 ) as curr_stock
from stock
group by dt
) t
```

Explanation: Inner query `t` is returning the sum of amount for that day by adding/subtracting based on `in` or `out`, group by date.

Now the outer query is using analytical function `sum() over (partition by` to do a cumulative sum.

Working sample

```
with stock(dt,Type,Amount) as (
select to_date('12.31.2000','MM.DD.YYYY'),'in',1000   from dual union all
select to_date('01.01.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'in', 150   from dual union all
select to_date('01.01.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'out', 500  from dual union all
select to_date('01.02.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'in', 400   from dual union all
select to_date('01.02.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'out', 150  from dual union all
select to_date('01.03.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'in', 300   from dual union all
select to_date('01.03.2001','MM.DD.YYYY'),'out', 50   from dual)

select t.dt,
  sum(curr_stock) over ( order by dt) as stock1
from 
( select dt,
          sum(case when type='out' then -1 * amount
                    else amount end
                 ) as curr_stock
from stock
group by dt
) t
```

Comment: This one did it. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'in' THEN +AMOUNT WHEN TYPE='out' THEN -AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS AMOUNT_TOT
FROM stock
WHERE DATE <= '2001-01-01'
```

Or, if it is more readable:

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT * CASE WHEN TYPE = 'in' THEN 1 WHEN TYPE='out' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS AMOUNT_TOT
FROM stock
WHERE DATE <= '2001-01-03'
```

Update after your comment (if you need all the days of a month, it's easy to do it using a tally date table and a left join with this query):

```
SELECT DATE,SUM(AMOUNT_TOT) OVER(ORDER BY DATE) AS DAY_BY_DAY
FROM (
    SELECT DATE, SUM(AMOUNT * CASE WHEN TYPE = 'in' THEN 1 WHEN TYPE='out' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) AS AMOUNT_TOT
    FROM stock
    GROUP BY DATE
    ) A
```

Comment: not really because i need a result, which gives out the different amounts on eacht day. And all in one result.
So basicly i need one query that returns several rows.
Each row needs to have what is in stock for that day.
Like 01.01.2001 - 01.31.2001. And the result should give out 31 records (each day of JAnuary) and what was in stock on each day.
So what was in stock on the 01.01., 01.02, 01.03, ...

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE stock ( "Date", Type, Amount ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2000-12-31', 'in',  1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-01', 'in',   150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-01', 'out',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-02', 'in',   400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-02', 'out',  150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-03', 'in',   300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2001-01-04', 'out',   50 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       "Date",
       SUM( CASE TYPE WHEN 'in' THEN Amount ELSE -Amount END ) OVER ( order by "Date" ) AS total
FROM   stock
ORDER BY "Date"
```

**Output**:

```
Date       TOTAL
---------- -----
2000-12-31  1000
2001-01-01   650
2001-01-02   900
2001-01-03  1150
```

Comment: That is genius. Nice elegant answer.

Comment: I added `order by` in `over (` clause as it won't work without that. But really a genius solution and use of `distinct` with `analytical` functions. My answer is moot now.

Answer (score 0):

I have no way to test it right now but this should do the trick:

```
SELECT INCOMMING.in - OUTGOING.out
FROM
    (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS 'in'
    FROM   stock
    WHERE  date <= <date> AND type = 'in'
    ) INCOMMING
JOIN
    (
    SELECT SUM(amount) AS 'out'
    FROM   stock
    WHERE  date <= <date> AND type = 'out'
    ) OUTGOING
ON
    1=1
```

**EDIT**

After your comment on etsas answer I understood that you'd like all possible entries in one query. Again I can't test it right now but this should be possible:

```
SELECT
    STOCKDATE.date,
    (
        SELECT
            INCOMMING.in - OUTGOING.out AS 'dailyCount'
        FROM
            (
            SELECT SUM(amount) AS 'in'
            FROM   stock
            WHERE  date <= STOCKDATE.date AND type = 'in'
            ) INCOMMING
        JOIN
            (
            SELECT SUM(amount) AS 'out'
            FROM   stock
            WHERE  date <= STOCKDATE.date AND type = 'out'
            ) OUTGOING
        ON
            1=1
    )
FROM stock STOCKDATE
```